# Store daily notification time in the PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design

I'd like to give the users the ability to select which time they'll get the notifications.

The should be able to select one or multiple hour values (0-24) and then get notified daily at selected hours.

Whats the best way to model it?

Was thinking about this solution: adding an ARRAY column within user table containing hours eg. [1, 6, 23] but dunno how fast it's gonna be during scanning the table each hour in order to find users to send notification to.

Comment: You can add a GiST or GIN index on the column which stores your array of time, or you can opt for a single time column and insert as many rows as notification times for the same user.

Comment: Just a tiny correction. Hour values would be 0-23.  1 sec after 23:59:59 is 00:00:00,  As for multiple notification times for a user just create multiple rows for the user.

Answer (score 0):

The array for all users would have to be read every hour just to find any occurrences of that hour. Seems a bit much.

A single row for each user for each hour then you only select the notifications that you actually need to send. Deletes/updates can easily be garbaged out of the DB.